# Как сделать правельный переход по ссылке

Tags: javascript, html

верстаю макетик и тут задался вопросом .

Как сделать переход по ссылке правильно , макет -

[image: макет]

код -

```
<ul class="list">
  <li>
    <div class="wrapper">
           <div class="image"></div>
           <h3>The whale and the polar bear: Lacanian considerations about DSM- V</h3>
           <div class="wrapper_info">
             <span>By Sergio Laia</span>
             <span>Audio in: Spanish</span>
           </div>
           <ol class="list">
            <li>Miquel</li>
            <li>Miquel</li>
            <li>Miquel</li>
            <li>Miquel</li>
            <li>Miquel</li>
         </ol>
      </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

как сделать это-т блок ссылкой ?
поместить все елементы в тег `<a>` , или можно получше сделать ?

Comment: Да, можно поместить все элементы в тег `a`

Comment: я нашёл способ с js - как будет правильнее - сделать через тег `a` или добавить блоку клас `.relocation` , добавить атрибут `data-link` где будет ссылка на страницу и через js обрабатывать клик и по блоку и в качестве ссылки брать значения с атрибута ?

Comment: Вы что-то не то нашли)) НАСТОЯТЕЛЬНО рекомендую прислушаться к @ПростаMiha :)

Comment: @IgorBiyar ну вы и заморочились, то есть вам легче будет использовать `js` для переадресаций а не завернуть всё в тег `a`? (⊙ˍ⊙)

Comment: Это как-то странно выглядит засувать весть блок в тег a , если у меня есть внутри блока другие теги a ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

‘’’

```
<a href=“#”>
  <div class=“container”></div>
</a>
```

‘’’